# Hackkerrank BitFlipping Challenge

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, unary-operator

Most are probably familiar with this problem but for those who are not:

> Given 32-bit unsigned integers flip their bits and print the resulting integers.

I was hoping that someone can give me clueson how to solve this in Java. Now I would normally provide some code i have tried but it was such a mess that it had to be deleted. I tried looking at the Editorial, which suggested using the bitwise `~` operator, but that didn't provide the required input. The example input/output was

Input:

```
3 (this is just the number of the integers that we are given)
2147483647 
1 
0
```

Output:

```
2147483648 
4294967294 
4294967295
```

P.S Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There in nothing wrong with the `~` operator. It does flip the bits. All you have to understand, is that in Java, `int` value are always *signed*.

But since “unsigned” is only a matter of interpretation of the bits, you have to print them like unsigned values, e.g. using Java 8:

```
int[] values={2147483647, 1, 0};
for(int value: values)
    System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(~ value));
```

will print

```
2147483648
4294967294
4294967295
```

If you can’t use Java 8, you can help yourself out by converting the `int` values to `long` before printing:

```
int[] values={2147483647, 1, 0};
for(int value: values)
    System.out.println((~ value) & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I seem to have forgotten that int values are signed.

Answer (score 1):

**REALLY THIS FLIPS ALL THE BITS**

```
it is normal that if you flip small number like

    000000000000000001 to inverse bits:
    111111111111111110
```

the result will be much bigger number.

```
int n=~n; // flips all bits to inverse, 1 to 0 and 0 to 1;
```

**if you wish to have only 32 bits do:**

```
int n=n&0xFFFFFFFF;
```

you can check the bits of an Integer in this way:

```
int x = 100;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share the answer in Kotlin, if suddenly someone needs :)

```
fun flippingBits(n: Long): Long {
    return n.inv() and 0xFFFFFFFFL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:
You need to flip bits. 1 becomes 0. 0 becomes 1. When does that happen?

```
1 xor 1 = 0
1 xor 0 = 1
```

So, any number xor `ff` should give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The java.math.BigInteger.flipBit(int n) returns a BigInteger whose value is equivalent to this BigInteger with the designated bit flipped

```
  // create 2 BigInteger objects
BigInteger bi1, bi2;

// assign value to bi1
bi1 = new BigInteger("8");//1000

// perform flipbit operation on bi1 with index 1
bi2 = bi1.flipBit(1);
```